# How to Add Top Adjustment Layer to All Images in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export

I've got a dozen layers or so in my `.psd` and I am trying to `Export Layers to Files...`, However, when exported, I want the top adjustment layer to take effect on every image.

My layers look a little like this:

```
- adjustment_layer
- layer_3
- layer_2
- layer_1
```

Is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38288/saving-each-layer-as-a-separate-image-photoshop-with-with-adjustments --- However, it is easier to run an action in a batch to multiple images, rather than to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

you could have the layers grouped up, add the adjustment to the group as a clipping mask and then export the group. That way, all the layers are exported with the adjustment made.

Hope it helps.