# Resizing multiple images inside one document within a set frame size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, actions

I'm hoping I can write this clearly.

I have a document with a number of cutout images in it on a transparent background. We want to resize each image so that the longest edge (either height or width) is 5inches. Is there an action I can set up to do this?

If I apply 'fit image' it just changes the overall size.

Any help much appreciated, I'm sure I'm missing something quite obvious!

Comment: It would be slightly easier if you have those images in a folder in you OS. Is there perhaps a reason why you'd have all those images inside one document? [Something like this perhaps?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38288/saving-each-layer-as-a-separate-image-photoshop-with-with-adjustments/38319)

Answer (score 1):

You were close! I created an *action* with the following steps:

1. `Layer > Smart Object > Convert to Smart Object`
2. `Layer > Smart Object > Edit Contents`
3. `File > Automate > Fit Image` (set your size requirements here)
4. `File > Save`
5. `File > Close`
6. `Layer > Smart Object > Rasterize Image`

This does what you were trying to do, but treats each layer you apply it to as its own file. Should do what you're looking for. If you'd like to just use my `.ATN` *Action file*, here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rpgjyl7h5suqly/Layer%20Resizer.atn?dl=0) (CS5).

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this in *Adobe Fireworks*. Here is an [article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d8df-7ffa.html) on how to do it.

Comment: Please consider building an answer from the relevant elements of the article you link to. If the link fails there won't be any content to speak of! Thank you!