# How to export a individual layer with a fixed master layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Let's say I have some layers and a single different one, or a group of layers I want to export merged together, in a way that every single exported layer is merged with a specific layer or group of layers.

In the example below I have some layers which need to be exported into JPG or PNG, merged with the very top layer called "Blurred". In my case, I want to export the layers (Jan 8 + Blurred) and (Layer 10 + Blurred) and so on. Acting as exporting layers merged with a master layer called "Blurred".

My question in a simple way: how to apply a Master layer(s)/Group(s) in Photoshop to be exported with every layer I have?

[image]

Comment: Something like [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38319/2332), right?

Comment: Thank you @joonas it is not exactly what I asked for but I can adapt my workflow. It could be worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this method:

We have a text layer on top and 3 coloured layers beneath:

[image: The Layers]

Open the Timeline panel and select "Make Frames From Layers" from the menu.

Delete the last frame, select all the remaining frames and turn on the top layer in the Layers panel. Now we have thumbnails of the files we need!

[image]

Select "Flatten Frames Into Layers" from the Timeline menu. Each of the flattened frames are added as new layers.

Turn on all of these new layers (and nothing else) and select "File/Scripts/Export Layers To Files". Make sure to select "Visible Layers Only".

I wouldn't save the document afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

[image: you can have something like this]

Maybe you can create groups for both layers "layer 10" and "Jan 8" and copy paste Blurred layer inside of them, that way if you make a change in blurred smart object it gonna appear on both groups, then just export every group selecting both and right click > export as

Please look at the image above as example

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I do it manually, I think I would be easier just to turn on/off layers. What I need is an automatic solution to a huge number of layers.