# Export separate layers as png from Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have 20 layers on Photoshop. Is there a simple way to get 5 different images without exporting them manually? I need them as separate files to feed into a script, and as of now I could only find a method to save the flattened image. 
I'd also be fine with a gif that goes through the separate layers.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell exactly what you are trying to do (and why you don't just do it manually since it would take less time to export 5 files than to ask this question). Maybe the method used in [my very first answer on this site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/83956/84899) can be inspiring?

Comment: I think I might use image assets generation in PS CC for this: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html - If you don't have the CC version, you might be able to find extensions or scripts that work similarly. But most of the extensions for like CS5 and CS6 have disappeared... They're not easy to come by at this point. I should add that there are also extensions and scripts that allow renaming layers in batch so you could easily append the file extension using those.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop CC you can do

> File > Export > Layers to Files

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use Image Assets feature.

Enable it in File > Generate > Image Assets.

eg: Name each layer to Layer 1.png, Layer 2.png...

You must name the layers with different names.

Photoshop will automatically save the layers as png in an assets folder.

See the iamge below:

[image]