# How to position an image into a background image and batch process?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I want to automate/batch process 1 image at a time and position into a background image, then save each image, 1 at a time).

All the images I want placed are the same dimensions ( the background is larger than the intended placed images).

I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

I can do it manually but how is it possible to do in photoshop or illustrator?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "position into background image"? You want to place the same image repeated *under* existing image content? Are these raster or vector images? There's most likely little to no point in using Illustrator is you only have raster images.

Comment: You have the batch sequence backwards. You would start with a bunch of images (usually a folder full of images that you want to process), record an action to place the background image, make any additional edits like changing the canvas size, re-positioning, swap layers, etc.  Save it, then quit the action recording, then apply the Action to the folder full of images using File > Automate > Batch.

Comment: A word of warning, work on copies of the images so you don't accidentally overwrite the originals.

Comment: see this related question (if not an exact duplicate): [Batch for pasting each image into a fixed one with action](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114777/batch-for-pasting-each-image-into-a-fixed-one-with-action/114778#114778)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback replies.  I seem to be getting closer to solving my problem.  What I want is basically the opposite of adding watermarks to each image (I'm trying to place separate portraits into the same background image, multiple times?) Sorry about the confusion. Thanks again for all the feedback and replies.

Comment: Have you tried what is described at the link I provided? Did it not work for you? What went wrong?

Comment: Hi,  Sorry if it is a duplicate to what I originally asked.  With the link provided I have read through it, but the processed files after batch mix together 50% top and 50% bottom (not of the background image, but the ones being processed on the stack), only the image I manually save is ok, the automation does the error.  Something I must be doing wrong, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by 50% top and 50% bottom? Can you share an image/screenshot showing what you are trying to achieve? If you can't show the images you are actually working on, use example images in their place.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in Photoshop, under Windows > Actions, you can record anything you wish to do and play the action afterward.

[image]